# How do I pass a parameter to ThreadManager.createThreadForCurrentRequest(new Runnable() in GAE?

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine

How can I pass a parameter to a `Thread`?

The statement `log( "before process , counter = " + i);`
causes an error:

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined in a different method

Please Help

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    Thread thread = ThreadManager.createThreadForCurrentRequest(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                log("before process , counter = " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                log("after process  ,      "  + "counter = " + i);

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted in loop:", ex);
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it said, just a final variable. That tells Java that it will not be changed and it can safely be used in the Runnable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    final int counter=i;
```

Comment: The problem is that a counter variable in a `for` loop can't be final... THere'll have to be another variable declared

Comment: It can be defined final! Since the scope of the counter variable is only the loop, after the loop iteration is finished it is gone anyway and for the next iteration it can be a new value. Just try for "for (final int i;...", it works.

Comment: Which JDK? Here, 1.6 or 1.7, Oracle's or OpenJDK, all yell at me when I do that

Comment: No, you're right, I was wrong. I missed one error marker. I am sorry.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but it is not working. the "i" is changed each time. how to pass a changed value, not final

Comment: it is working. with fge's help and i changed and tested. i can pass parameter to thread. thanks to all your help again

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    final int counter = i;
    // etc
}
```

then use `counter` in your thread instead of `i` (which, as the error message tells you, is not final, thus cannot be used in this situation).

Comment: you can just define i as final.

Comment: I am use google app engine for java. there is only thing I can use is "import com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager". Can you anybody give me a sample code to pass a parameter to Thread ?

Comment: Just reuse your code but create the `counter` variable as shown, and in the thread you create, replace `i` with `counter`; that will solve the problem.

Comment: thanks for  fge . It seems working. let me test and reply later